# Conditional formatting for concatenated cells

Tags: excel, concatenation, conditional-formatting

As a fun project I decided to analyze some stats for a game I play. I made some tables showing the amount of times certain duo's of classes were played, and a seperate table that shows the winrates for these duo's. See screenshots below.

[image: Duo's #]

[image: Duo's WR]

As you can see, the winrates table has conditional formatting. For a better overview of the stats, I concatenated these two tables, resulting in the one pasted below.

[image: Duos concatenated]

My question is the following: how can I get the same conditional formatting from the second table in my concatenated table (so, sorted based on the %value)?

Any help would be very welcome! :)

Comment: You won't be able to apply the color-scale-conditional formatting to the merged table - this can only be applied to number only cells

Comment: I suppose you could use about ten different individual custom formatting rules to get a similar effect